# Android statusbar and actionbar resolve to grey

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar, statusbar

I recently split my values into two:

- *values/style.xml*
- *values-v21/style.xml*

my v21/style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Foodie" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Foodie" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

And my toolbar:

```
<!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
     in front of the action bar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Somehow, we toolbar background's resolve to grey! Same for the statusbar when I compile:

[image: grey action bar]

And I'm not sure if that's linked, but I recently cleaned my project before building it.

Do you know what's happening?

Comment: You using same parent theme for v21 and others!!? (`parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`)

Comment: And have you run application on device? There might be rendering issues in Android Studio. @Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Use Toolbar code like this:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            //..........

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in `style.xml` will like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```